# matrix product with trace zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

$D$ is a positive definite matrix, $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite matrices, $c$ is a postive integer. I want to know whether $trace\{(A+B+cI)^{-1}ABD\}=0$ implies that $AB=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\!, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 0 \end{bmatrix}\!, \quad D = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\!, \quad c = 1.$$
Then
$$(A + B + cI)^{-1} A B D = \frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 4 & -2 \end{bmatrix}\!,$$
so $\mathop{\rm tr}((A + B + cI)^{-1} A B D) = 0$, but
$$AB = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

**Acknowledgment:** Example fixed by Sebastien B's comments.

Comment: I hope I did not make another dumb mistake, but when I compute $(A+B+cI)^{-1} ABD$ I get $(A+B+cI)^{-1}=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$, the same $AB$ as you and thus $(A+B+cI)^{-1} ABD=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ whose trace is nonvanishing.

Comment: You're right; I had a typo in Mathematica code I used to calculate this. I'll try to look into it some more. Thanks.

Comment: But if you take $D=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, I think your example is fine: $(A+B+cI)^{-1} ABD=\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1/2 \\ 2 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you. I've multiplied your $D$ by $2$, to keep it visually nicer (less fractions).

Comment: If it is constrainted that the positive definite matrix $D$ should satisfy $D=(A+B+eI)^{-1}$ where $e$ is also a postive integer, can you give another example?

Comment: Take the same example, for $e = 1$. This will give you $$D = \frac{1}{5} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$ and the rest will be more or less the same (factor $1/5$). This is due to the structure of $B$, so the second row of $D$ has no effect on your expression, and the rest is as above (just divided by $5$, which doesn't affect the fact that the trace is zero).

Comment: If I change the constraint that the positive definite matrix $D$ should satisfy that $D=(A-AFA+B-BFB+eI)^{-1}$ where $e$ is a positive integer and $F=(A+B+cI)^{-1}$. Then whether $trace\{FABD\}=0$ implies that $AB=0$?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe you should think what it is you're really after and then open a new question for the people to help you. Chasing numerous counterexamples is just not very productive, especially when compared to the time and effort needed to come up with each one.